# How to loop through dict using a counter

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

So I am trying to make a sort loop using `dict`. What I am trying to do is that I have two different json files in my folder where I want to apply each `dict` for each json file. Meaning the `json` file 1 would be the first in dict and the second json file would the second dict.

```
discordHooks = {'swedish': [
                'https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/ASDFDFGDSFGSDFG',
                'https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/EAAEFAEFAFlF'],
                'italian':[
                'https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/qwertyuiop',
                'https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/lkjahgfdsa']
            }

def sendToDiscord():
    directory = os.fsencode('./slack')
    for counters, file in enumerate(os.listdir(directory)):
        filename = os.fsdecode(file)
        if filename.endswith(".json"):
            with open('./slack/' + filename) as slackAttachment:
                 print(discordHooks.get('italian', [counters]))
```

My idea here is that I want it to loop through each json file using `for counters, file in enumerate(os.listdir(directory)):` and what I want it to happend is that the first loop would be the first json file == should print out the first dict value and the next loop would be second dict value.

However I do not know how to do it and I do not want to use lists either.

How am I able to loop through each dict so the first loop of json file would be first value of dict and the second loop would be the second value of dict?

---

Update:

In my folder I have two json files where the first one is called `Thrill.json` and second file is `HelloWorld.json` and those are always the same (There wont be added new json files or removed json at any time).

So for now I am using the code:

```
discordHooks = {'swedish': [
                'https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/ASDFDFGDSFGSDFG',
                'https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/EAAEFAEFAFlF'],
                'italian':[
                'https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/qwertyuiop' #This going tobe applied for the first json,
                'https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/lkjahgfdsa' #this going to applied to second json]
            }

def sendToDiscord():
    directory = os.fsencode('./slack')
    for counters, file in enumerate(os.listdir(directory)):
        filename = os.fsdecode(file)
        if filename.endswith(".json"):
            with open('./slack/' + filename) as slackAttachment:
                 print(discordHooks.get('italian', [counters]))
```

so basically what I am trying to do is that I want the first json `Thrill` to print out the first value in the list which is `https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/qwertyuiop` and when the that is done we go through the second loop which is going to print out `https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/lkjahgfdsa`

And thats pretty much it, There is values inside the json files that I will apply later in the code (Nothing I have coded yet) but it is important that the first json file will have the first webhook from italian[0] basically. and the second json file will have the second webhook italian[1].

I hope this is more clear now! :)

Comment: list all the file path in a list, then read file using with open and using json.load add that dict file to your dic

Comment: Make the keys of your dictionary the filenames and don't use enumerate, i.e. replace `'Hello'` with `"file_1.json"`

Comment: @Dan I dont quite get it how I would get it done, Is it possible if you could make a simple code example?

Comment: @Thrillofit86 sure, added an answer

Comment: But what about `swedish`...?

Comment: Swedish will also have URL, I forgot to add it @Dan Updated it now :)

Comment: "Swedish will also have URL"... one each for Thrill and HelloWorld? Why does it only have one in your example?

Comment: @Dan Wops! I updated the wrong code! It is now updated :D

Comment: @Thrillofit86 OK, I've made my last update. good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from pathlib import Path


def make_language_dict(thrill_hook: str, helloworld_hook: str):
    return {
        "Thrill": thrill_hook
        "HelloWorld": helloworld_hook
    }


discord_hooks = {
                    'swedish': make_language_dict(
                        thrill_hook='https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/ASDFDFGDSFGSDFG',
                        helloworld_hook='https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/EAAEFAEFAFlF'
                    ),
                    'italian':make_language_dict(
                        thrill_hook='https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/qwertyuiop',
                        helloworld_hook='https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/lkjahgfdsa'
                    ),
                }

def send_to_discord(directory: Path = Path(r"./slack")):
    for filepath in directory.glob("*.json"):
        with open(filepath.resolve()) as slack_attachment:
            for language in discord_hooks:
                 discord_hook = discord_hooks[language][filepath.stem]
                 print(discord_hook)
                 # Do stuff with the file and the discord_hook here...
```

Comment: I will try give it a go and see :) WIll be back soon with result

Comment: The issue with such a solution is that you cannot garantee that all files in the directory will have matching keys... and given how easy it is to add a file in a directory, this is brittle at best. NB: not saying the solution is totally wrong, just wanted to highight the possible cons...

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers that's true. Should I wrap it with `try:` `except KeyError:`. It sounds like this dictionary might make more sense as a config file.

Comment: I have now updated my thread adding *discordHooks* maybe it is easier now to loop through each list in dict? I havent been able to figure out how to loop now through the list which is inside the dict.

Comment: @Thrillofit86 your question is unclear, can you provide an example of the files you can expect (just the names). Is there a 1-to-1 match between the files and the keys of the `discordHook` dictionary?

Comment: @Dan There we go, I think I have now explained it abit better. If there is anything else that is unclear, please feel free to comment here again.

Comment: @Thrillofit86 I have updated it. It's still completely unclear what you want to do with the different languages...

Comment: I am almost where I wanted! However this code have some type err where u have an `:` in the `discord_hook = discord_hooks[language][filepath]:` and also it doesnt seem to print out each webhook either `KeyError: WindowsPath('slack/Thrill.json')`

Comment: @Thrillofit86 try now, I also update the function at the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

`counters` is an int and your dict's keys are strings (and mostly arbitrary ones AFAICT) so obviously this cannot work as expected.

If you don't care at all about ordering (if there's actually no real relationship between the directory content and the `test` dict content), you can just use the dict's values as a list:

```
test_list = list(test.values())
for i, fname in enumerate(os.listdir(...)):
    print("i : {} - fname : {} - value : {}".format(i, fname, test_list[i]))
```

Just note that this will crash if you have more entries in your directory than you have in your dict, obviously.

If ordering matters, then you have a couple other issues...

The first one is that Python dicts are unordered until 3.7.x so if you want a solution that does work with older Python versions you just cannot use a plain dict - you need either a `collections.OrderedDict` or just a plain list of `(key, value)` tuples (from which you can rebuild a dict: `vals = [("foo": "xxx"), ("bar: "yyy")]; test = dict(vals)`)

The second issue is that `os.listdir()` is specifically documented as not being ordered either (or, more exactly, as being "arbitrary ordered", which means you cannot rely on the ordering being the same even for two consecutive calls on the same path from the same process), and here there's not much you can do except eventually sorting the list manually.

To make a long story short: if there's supposed to be any relationship between the directory's content and your data, you do have to explicitely implement this relationship yourself one way or another.

**EDIT**: given your updated question, the proper solution would be to take the issue the other way round: configure the url->filename mapping in python, and read the files from this mapping, ie:

```
# We're going to need this to solve possible path issues
# (relying on the current working directory is a recipe for headaches)
# NB: we assume the json files are in _HERE/slack/)
_HERE = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

discordHooks = {
    # list of `(url, filename)` pairs
    'italian':[
      ('https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/qwertyuiop', 'jsonfile1.json'),
      ('https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/lkjahgfdsa' , 'jsonfile2.js')
    ]
}

for url, filename in discordHooks["italian"]:
    path = os.path.join(_HERE, "slack", filename)
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        # Don't know how you want to handle the case...
        raise ValueError("file {} not found".format(path))
    print("url: {} - path: {}".format(url, path))
```

Comment: Ahhh I see! Alright that makes sense now when I have read all this. So meaning I need to rework on what I am trying to accomplish here. Maybe I am thinking doing everything over complicated but I do get it more thanks to you!